# Using Computer Vision for Android Sudoku Solver

Tags: java, android, computer-vision

Forgive me if I've missed a similar SO question, but I have not found any related to my specific problem.

I wanted to write a sudoku solver for android.  This part of the problem seems straight forward and well documented elsewhere.

However, I wanted to be able to take a picture of a physical puzzle on paper and then use this to generate a java representation of the puzzle that can then be solved.

While I'm not new to java or android, I am new to computer vision. So I am wondering what strategies or concepts would be most effective in solving the problem of **how to translate a sudoku puzzle from a picture captured by android to a sudoku puzzle in memory that can be solved.**  Even knowing key terms would help me narrow my search down from Computer Vision 101.

Thanks!

## Edit

Removed library recommendation from question to better conform with SO standards.

Comment: please read [ask]. Asking for library recommendations is considered off-topic on SO.
You'll need some sort of number/character recognition. Google for OCR.
If you are limited to printed numbers and fonts are always the same or very similar, simpler methods might work as you only have 9 things to differentiate.

Comment: I removed library recommendation from the question.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a cool project! I've done some character recognition in the past and the term you want to be Googling is [OCR - Optical Character Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition). The first result on Google came up with a [neat little project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238114/Realtime-Webcam-Sudoku-Solver) someone made to recognise sudoku puzzles from a computer webcam. I haven't downloaded it and run it, but skimming the page it seems to have quite a bit of detail that is probably transferable to Android.

In terms of Android specific OCR code, there's [this project](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr) that calls itself

> An experimental app for Android that performs optical character recognition (OCR) on images captured using the device camera.

I think you'll be able to find a lot of other sources on the interweb, using the search term "OCR" will be your gateway keyword here...

Answer (score 1):

I came to this question from a google search and I'm not sure if you are still looking for the answers.

There are many algorithms for making a sudoku solver android app; however, based on my personal experience I would suggest using OpenCV in android for this particular problem.

There are many tutorials to getting started with OpenCV hence I'm not going to recommend any in this.

The algorithms for such app are as follows

1. Canny edge detection followed by blurring to remove the noise
2. Contour edge detection is applied to get the rectangles in the image
3. Based on the contour area sort the contour in descending order
4. Find the lengths of the top 5 rectangles to get the squares. Now that the sudoku
5. Wrap perspective transformation is applied to the contour
6. Divided the image equally to get the cells
7. In order to find the number either use KNN or AutoML.
8. From there you could solve the sudoku manually or you can use any algorithm to solve it.

I have created one of such app and posted it on [GitHub](https://github.com/dreamerchandra/sudokusolver).

[Here is a quick demo of it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpD2xlgQ-3w)